# Как привести в читаемый вид код js?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

Нужно редактировать сжатый js-код.
Никогда раньше с этим не сталкивался.

Подскажите, как в php-шторме (или другим способом) привести такой код к читаемому и визуально-понятно редактируемому?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такой код можно только отформотрировать. А больше ничего вы сделать и не сможете.

Comment: А как отформатировать?

Comment: На сколько я помню, **ctrl+alt+l**

Comment: Больше всего доставили магические числа переводов в этом "поделии"

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko отформатировался js, но html так и остался. А нужен был как раз html. Да, я неправильно видимо поставил вопрос.

Comment: Если вам нужен отформатированный html, то лучше на сайте зайдите в devTools, найдите там нужный вам html и скопируйте его.

Comment: Он там не отображается. HTML формируется в браузере посредством js.

Comment: Вот тут, в один клик https://www.10bestdesign.com/dirtymarkup/ и не только js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Форматируем, выравниваем код сочетанием клавиш:

---

**Ctrl + Alt + L**